# Global FPSB not to renew its licensing agreement with FPSB India what does it mean for the current & future CFP aspirants

Tags: india, financial-advisor

Global FPSB has decided not to renew its licensing agreement with FPSB India. [Reference link](https://www.business-standard.com/article/markets/global-financial-planning-body-decides-not-to-renew-pact-with-fpsb-india-118072800009_1.html)
The agreement between FPSB and FPSB India expires on March 31, 2020.

I plan to become a Registered Investment Advisor(RIA) in India.
I am aware that to become a RIA there are 2 ways to get that.

1. **NISM (National Institute of Securities Markets)**:

   Need to clear these two exams to apply for RIA.

   - NISM – Series-X-A: Investment Adviser (Level-1) Certification Examination
   - NISM - Series – X-B: Investment Adviser (Level-2) Certification Examination
2. **FPSB (Financial Planning Standards Board) - India**:

   FPSB India agreement with the Global FPSB will not be renewed after 31st March 2020.

**My Questions is as follows:**

1. Does is mean that NISM will be the only way to get your RIA after 8 months from now.
2. What will happen to FPSB India after the agreement has been terminated.
3. Out of NISM and FPSB which is the better way to go for to gather more knowledge as an financial advisor.

Comment: [This link](https://www.fpsb.org/member/financial-planning-standards-board-india/) may be of interest: "_Effective 1 April 2019, Financial Planning Standards Board Ltd. (FPSB Ltd.), owner of the international CERTIFIED FINANCIAL PLANNER certification program outside the United States, has taken over administration of India’s CFP certification program._"

Comment: @TripeHound Thanks a lot for the link. Have dropped them a mail with my Queries.

Comment: Glad to help. If you get a reply, consider self-answering your question (a practice freely allowed).

Comment: Sure will do that.